# Customize the menu depending on situation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

How can I customize the menu to the situation in WPF?
I have a main window with a basic menu. In this window, I can load different UserControls and then I want the menu to be expanded with different menu options depending on which User Control is used.

Example:

```
Main menu:
File
   Open
   -
   MRU
   -
   Exit


For viewing of UserControl 1:
File
   Open
   Edit
   -
   MRU
   -
   Exit

For viewing of UserControl 2:
File
   Open
   Edit
   -
   MRU
   -
   Exit
View
   Show codes
   Show capital letters

In Editing
File
   Open
   Save
   Save as...
   -
   MRU
   -
   Exit
Edit
   Add
   Remove
   Move
   -
   Cancle Edit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would bind the menu to a Collection, and have the different UserControls alter the Collection when loaded.

EDIT - Here's an example

Your main View would contain something like this

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentUserControl.MenuItems}">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MenuItemText}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommand}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommandParameter}" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
</Menu>
```

While each UserControl would contain a Collection property of the MenuItems you would like to display

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string MenuItemText {get; set;}
    public ICommand MenuItemCommand {get; set;}
    public object MenuItemCommandParameter {get; set;}
}
```

...

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems;
```

Comment: But then the ui is created from the ViewModel thats break MVVM. The menus should be in the View of the respective userControl, and in any way be merged with the menu in the main program.

Comment: You would still create your Menus in the View, however you would bind them to an ItemsSource that is defined in the ViewModel instead of manually building your MenuItems in the View.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you mean. Yes, I create the main menu of view, but its customization is done in the View Model.

Comment: @magol I added some sample code to my answer. I don't have time to do a full mock up of it but I hope this will point you in the right direction

Comment: This answer is a very good way to do it, and is exactly in line with MVVM.  Your ViewModel is an abstraction of your View.  The components that populate the menus should come from the ViewModel for that view.  As Rachel points out, the ViewModel for each control has a collection of menu options that the Menu control can bind to.  You'd have to make sure that OnPropertyChanged is called for "CurrentUserControl.MenuItems" when you switch controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CompositeCollection to merge multiple collection into one.
Following the example from [1](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Object}" x:Key="extensions">
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 2" />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 3" />
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <MenuItem Header="Standard MenuItem 1" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Standard MenuItem 2" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Standard MenuItem 3" />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource extensions}" />
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did found a solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/WPFMergeMenu.aspx
But there should be something better

Answer (score 0):

How about binding the visibility of certain menu options to booleans in the ViewModel, and using an IValueConverter to switch between Visible and Collapsed?

Comment: But then all menus a coded in the main window. If I want to add och chang a View, then I also have to change the Main View.

Comment: I might have been working with IValueConverter too much recently...
Maybe you can create a converter that takes a menu as its argument to "convert" a menu to a merge between the argument and the value?
Then the main window menu is bound to the usercontrol menu, with a menu resource as the converter argument. The downside is that you'll have to edit your main window menu in the resources. And it's not going to be pretty at all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to build a series of if-then constructs in your code behind, to change the visibility of various menu items, depending on what user controls are visible.